# Render The Same Model Multiple Times

Tags: performance, opengl, 3d, rendering

What I'm trying to do, is basically having 1 model which gets rendered multiple times, with different translations and rotations.

So I know how to use `Array Buffers` and `Array Element Buffers` (`Vertex Buffer Objects`), my question is. That now when I've loaded the model into a `VBO` what would be the best approach if I wanted to render it multiple times with different translations and rotations.

I have 2 theories for how this could be done. (Though I'm asking what would be the best approach).

1. Load the model into one `VBO` and then keep calling `glDrawArrays` and apply the translation and rotation, for each model I want rendered.
2. Load the model into one `VBO` multiple times. The same model then gets stored multiple times, *which ends up using a lot of memory.*

**Extra:** *When doing the **1** way, Quadtrees and/or Frustum can be used which would minimize the amount of models required to be rendered.*

Which one of these ways would then be the best to do, if I want high FPS and still save the most amount of memory possible, or is there another approach which is even better?

*Just to clarify I'm not asking how to render using `VBO's` or how to render in general, I'm asking what is the best approach when you want to render the same model multiple times.*

#### Test Model

This is just an image of the test model.

[image: Demo Model]

#### Edit

I'm currently using OpenGL version 4.2.0, and I'm using it on a Windows desktop computer.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I edited the tags, I mean OpenGL for desktop.

Comment: Actually, if you want to do this the most efficient way, you'd use instancing. See: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing, the idea is to use `Uniform Buffer Objects` to store an array of transform information that you can index in your vertex shader using the instance id.

Comment: Sorry for the brevity, I'll try to write a formal explanation tomorrow when I have time. I'll say this right now though - your ultimate solution is going to be dependent upon your target OpenGL version, and you have not listed that in your question; excellent question otherwise though! >> Instancing became a core feature in OpenGL in 3.1 (dx10 class hardware).

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know Instancing was a thing. Though you wouldn't be able to perform Quadtree and/or Frustum Culling on all the instances.

Comment: Use instanced rendering with uniform buffer for matrices.

Answer (score 4):

To minimize draw calls and uniforms transfer you can use [glDrawArrayInstanced()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArraysInstanced.xml).This way,you submit as many instances of the original object as you wish in a single draw call!Matrices for each instance you can pack into UBO(uniform buffer object) and access those in the vertex shader per instance with [gl_InstanceID](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_InstanceID.xml)

Comment: Though when using that, the use of Quadtrees and/or Frustum Culling would be impossible. Thereby, if I have like 10K models, then I would probably get a low framerate, using that way.

Comment: You can cull geometry in shaders.Google for it ;)

Comment: In fact,you can even cull it with CPU approach.Before the draw call you probably already know which object would be outside the frustum (testing against instances matrices).So the out-of-frustum instances shouldn't be submitted .That's it.